# Mysql compare if date is at least two day away from now

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, has field named date with type date.

I have a row with date=2021-08-11, I want to perform an update, if table.date is more than 2 days from current, update it, else skip it.

```
update tableA set count = 10 where id=26 and date > (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 2 DAY);
//date is 2021-08-11.
```

the query returns:
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Can someone give me some help!?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might have a time zone issue.

Comment: Yes.. It is a time zone issue, the server has now as 2021-08-09.. Thanks. After re-set the server time zone and restart mysql sever, it is good now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DATE_ADD` and enclose your `date` variable inside `DATE()`. And you might want to use `CURDATE` instead of `DATE(NOW())` - but they are also the same, just to shorten your query.

```
UPDATE tableA set count = 10 
WHERE id=26 and DATE(`date`) > DATE_ADD(CURDATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

Comment: Thanks, This is new to me I will try to follow this way on my other queries.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see any problem -- why are you expecting the row updated?

Today is 2021/8/9, add 2 days is 2021/8/11

Your date is 2021/8/11, so date > 2 days later 2021/8/11 > 2021/8/11 is false.

You need to add some data as 2021/8/12 or later to make the updat happen.

Comment: The time I called the query was 2021-08-08 locally, which (2021-08-08)+2 day = 2021-08-10, and date in the row is 2021-08-11, which should trigger the true case, but the issue was, the mysql server had time zone as 2021-08-09, which it triggered the false case. So this is a server time zone issue instead of the query itself.